# Display True/False data type value to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I like to display the value of database which is stored as True/False datatype.
I want to render this data to dropdownlist.

So when the value is "true" in database, i like to display it as "Yes" in dropdownlist.
and if the value is "false" in database, i like to display as "No" in dropdownlist.

```
DataSet ds = getDetails(username);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
    TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fName"].ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lName"].ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();

    if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admin"]) == 0) {
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Yes";

    }
}
```

What i have tried is, i add two items in dropdownlist, one "Yes" with value "Yes" and another "No" with value "No".

In above code, i convert true/false to int type and compare it with another int.
As database stores true=0 and false= -1, i compare that in the code to make dropdownlist Yes or No.

But it is not working.
Does anyone have easy solution to this?

Comment: *not working* in what sense ? What is the value you get in `Convert`, is the if evaluated . you would also need the **else** part which should set `No`

Comment: Can't you just add only one, and the same column, and then, when you get the value in dataBase, affect yes or no depends on the value in DB?

Comment: it doesn't change dropdownlist to Yes or No. It always stays as Yes..

Comment: Are you saying your database stores true as 0 and false as -1, or you think that's what it's storing true and false as.  Usually true is 1 and false is 0 (or any number other than 1), but there are some databases that don't follow that (like Access, I believe).

Comment: Did you add the yes no dropdown items  with the ``value`` set to "Yes" and "No"

Comment: where is your code of setting `No` value? In the sample code in question, there is no such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just missing the `else` clause?

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admin"]) == 0) {
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Yes";
} else {
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "No";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdownlist should have 2 items.

- One with value `"-1"` which represent false.
- One with value `"0"` which represent true.

`Note: the standard value are 0 for false and 1 for true, you might want to use those eventually`

You're of course free to set their text as "true"/"false" or whatever.

Then you just set the SelectedValue to your column's actual value.

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admin"].ToString();
```